# QWT в Qt, навигация по графику

Tags: qt

Я пишу QWT виджет, на график можно добавить несколько кривых, так что они будут в одной системе координат:

```
void Plot::addCurve1( double x, double y, const char *CurveName,
                      const char *CurveColor,const char *CurveType )
{
...
    *points1 << QPointF(x, y);
    curve1->setSamples( *points1 );
    curve1->attach( this );
...
}
```

Я пытаюсь написать интерфейс навигации по графику, таким образом, чтобы можно было задавать шаг (в поле TextEdit, к примеру), и перемещаться по графику с этим шагом, или переместиться в начало/конец кривой по нажатию кнопки. Я нашел метод в классе QwtPlotPanner, который позволяет перемещаться по полю графика и выполнил следующую реализацию:

```
double QWT_widget::move_XLeft()
{
    //getting step from TextEdit
    QString xValStr = _XNavDiscrepancies->toPlainText();
    double xVal = xVal.toDouble();
    // moveCanvas(int dx, int dy) - the method of QwtPlotPanner
    plot->panner->moveCanvas(xVal,0);
    x_storage = x_storage - xVal;
    return x_storage;
}
```

И это работает, но проблема в том, что шаг задается в пикселях, и нет никакой привязки к системе координат. В Qwt User's Guide я нашел лишь эту информацию:

> Adjust the enabled axes according to dx/dy Parameters dx Pixel offset
>   in x direction dy Pixel offset in y direction

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ перейти от шага в пикселях к шагу в системе координат? Или может я вовсе использую не тот класс/метод ? Буду чертовски благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для перевода из координат в значение и обратно служат функции:  QwtPlot::transform и  QwtPlot::invTransform